# When I drag and drop a file into the art.scnassets folder in my AR Kit project, the file doesn't show

Tags: ios, file, scenekit, arkit

It shows up when I view art.scnassets in finder, but not in the side of the Xcode editor. How do I fix this?

Comment: If you can see it in finder, simple re-add it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

The possibilities comes in my mind are:

- change 'Point of View' below the scene to 'top' or 'front' to find out whether the object exists

  - the scale (too small/large) or the position(too far(x,y,z)) of the object on the scene. Check them from the right - utilities > node inspector > transforms.
- check whether visibility box is checked from the above location.
- set some texture on the object from material inspector.

hope it helps :)